# chart.js mix chart (bar + line): get lines to start at x = 0

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to plot a chart with two bars and two lines. the issue is that the lines wont go start at 0.

[image]

I have tried to artificially create points on the x axis to make them go all the way but it won't do the trick. Here is what my code look like for the graph:

```js
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
     type: 'bar',
     data: {
         labels: document.getElementById('tag1').textContent == 'ITEM TIME SUPPLY ANALYSIS'? ["Desired time supply","Actual time Supply"] :[ 'jours de stock désirés','jours de stock actuel'] ,
         datasets: [{
             label: document.getElementById('tag1').textContent == 'ITEM TIME SUPPLY ANALYSIS'? "limit max time supply (days)": "limite max jours de stock désirés",
             data: [
                {
                     x: 0,
                     y: [{% for dr in reference %} {{ dr.cap_ts }}, {% endfor %}]
                 },
                 {
                     x: 30,
                     y: [{% for dr in reference %} {{ dr.cap_ts }}, {% endfor %}]
                 },
                 {

                     x: 60,
                     y: [{% for dr in reference %} {{ dr.cap_ts }}, {% endfor %}]
                 },

                 {
                     x: 90,
                     y: [{% for dr in reference %} {{ dr.cap_ts }}, {% endfor %}]
                 },
             ],
             type: 'line',
             backgroundColor: [
                 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
             ],
             borderColor: [
                 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
             ],
             borderWidth: 5
         }, {
             label: document.getElementById('tag1').textContent == 'ITEM TIME SUPPLY ANALYSIS'? "limit min time supply (days)": "limite min jours de stock désirés",
             data: [
                 {
                     x: 0,
                     y: [{% for dr in reference %}{{ dr.min_ts}}, {% endfor %}]
                 },
                 {
                     x: 30,
                     y: [{% for dr in reference %}{{ dr.min_ts}}, {% endfor %}]
                 },
                 {
                     x: 60,
                     y: [{% for dr in reference %}{{ dr.min_ts}}, {% endfor %}]
                 },

                 {
                     x: 90,
                     y: [{% for dr in reference %}{{ dr.min_ts}}, {% endfor %}]
                 },
             ],
             type: 'line',
             backgroundColor: [
                 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
             ],
             borderColor: [
                 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
             ],
             borderWidth: 3
         }, { 

             data: [ 
                 {x:30,
                     y: {% for dr in reference %}{{ dr.dts}}, {% endfor %}
                 },
                 { x: 60,
                     y: {% for dr in reference %}{{ dr.actual_ts}}, {% endfor %}
                 },
             ],
             backgroundColor: [
                 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)'
             ],
             borderColor: [
                 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)'
             ],
             borderWidth: 1
         }]
     },
     options: {
         scales: {
             scaleShowLabels: false,
             type: 'linear',
             position: 'bottom',
             xAxes: [{
                 maxBarThickness: 90,
                 ticks: {
                     beginAtZero: true,
                 }
             }],
             yAxes: [{
                 ticks: {
                     beginAtZero: true,
                 }
             }]
         }
     }

 })
```

At this point I don't know what to try, I can't find much on chart.js documentation and I am new to javascript, any help would be very appreciated on this

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because chart.js sets the `offset` property in the `x` scale to true for bar charts so the bar is in the middle of the grid instead of on the  gridLine as is with line charts.

You can set the offset to false but then the first and last bar will look weird because they are half of the width.

Live example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        borderColor: 'red'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        type: 'bar',
        backgroundColor: 'blue'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        offset: false
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.4.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```